# Which is the more efficient function for splitting an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, performance

Which function is more efficient, memory-wise for splitting an array in PHP; array_slice() OR array_chunk()?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
After profiling both functions, memory usage seems to be the same, however array_chunk is faster by a tiny margin.

Comment: Beware premature optimization. Unless you're getting memory errors from PHP, or the server PHP is running on is suffering from excessive page thrashing, you don't need to be worrying about this.  In the former case, you can probably just raise the memory_limit value in php.ini to a bigger number, its set to a fairly conservative value by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) to profile them and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want in return? If you just want one chunk, use the slice.